# Как преобразовать список словарей со списками в список словарей другого вида с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, коллекции, словари

Здравствуйте!
Есть список такого вида:

```
[
  {
    "trend": [
        -298,
        -1177,
        -1298
        ]
  },
  {
    "dum": [
        67176,
        158560,
        161509
        ]
  }
]
```

Не могу понять как сделать итерацию по списку таким образом:

```
[
  {"trend": -298, "dum": 67167},
  {"trend": -1177, "dum": 158560},
  {"trend": -1298, "dum": 161509}
]
```

Прошу подсказать как это можно сделать на Python.

Спасибо.

Comment: Тут похоже на опечатку: ` {"trend": -298, "dum": 67167},` значение ведь будет 67176

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы `NxM` данные превратить в `MxN` (аналогично транспонированию для матриц): N словарей с одним уникальным ключём каждый, содержащие M-элементные списки, превращаются в один список с M словарями, у каждого по N ключей:

```
items = [{'a': [1,2,3]}, {'b': "АБВ"}]
keys = [next(iter(d.keys())) for d in items]  # -> ['a', 'b']
all_values = zip(*[next(iter(d.values())) for d in items])  # (1, 'А'), (2, 'Б'),..
transposed_items = [dict(zip(keys, values)) for values in all_values]
```

Здесь два словаря с трёх-элементными списками превращаются в три словаря с двумя ключами каждый:

```
>>> transposed_items
[{'a': 1, 'b': 'А'}, {'a': 2, 'b': 'Б'}, {'a': 3, 'b': 'В'}]
```

Comment: Круто, спасибо! То, что надо и нет зависимости от количества ключей в items.

Answer (score 5):

Код:

```
items = [{"trend": [-298, -1177, -1298]}, {"dum": [67176, 158560, 161509 ]}]

trends = items[0]['trend']
dums = items[1]['dum']

result = [{"trend": trend, "dum": dum} for trend, dum in zip(trends, dums)]
print(result)
```

Результат:

```
[{'trend': -298, 'dum': 67176}, {'trend': -1177, 'dum': 158560}, {'trend': -1298, 'dum': 161509}]
```